# JavaScript block CSS

Tags: javascript, css, firefox-addon

I have a .js file which blocks all CSS Code quite well when used with GreaseMonkey, but I also need it to run as .xpi (Firefox Extension) and it doesn't to work that well.

I have tried many things, and now I'm trying to debug it with the Firefox Extension Builder SDK so I get all the error messages. Here is the error message I get:

```
console.error: css3blocker: 
Message: ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

and here is the .js Code:

```
[].slice.call(document.styleSheets) .forEach(function (sheet) {
try {
   [].slice.call(sheet.cssRules) .forEach(function (rule) {
       if (rule.media) {
           rule.media.mediaText = '';
       }
   });
} catch (err) {
   console.log(err);
}
});
```

What does that error mean?

Comment: I think you need to rewrite it specifically as an extension, including whatever permissions needed to access page content.

Comment: It means that the `document` variable is not defined. Are you sure that you it is, if the js is ran as an extension?

Comment: What do you mean by "writing it speciffically as extention"? Im doing that or not?

and im also running it as extention over the cfx command line..

How would i define the document variable? is it not predefined in JS like document.cookie?

Comment: Okay i think i know the answer, document is not defined because the script runs before the website is even loaded, so i need to run the script at the end of the loading process. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

BIG BIG BIG BIG BIG BIG THANKS TO Noitidart!!!!!

You helped me A LOT!!

Got it to work now, the xpi is kinda more aggressiv as the JS over GreaseMonkey, but it wokrs now!

Changed the JS to this:

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
pageMod.PageMod({
 include: "*",
 contentScript: '[].slice.call(document.styleSheets) .forEach(function (sheet) {try {[].slice.call(sheet.cssRules) .forEach(function (rule) {if (rule.media) {rule.media.mediaText=\'\';}});} catch (err) {console.log(err);}});'    
});
```

And it works over the XPI Builder! :D

Answer (score 0):

### Method 1 - preference

To block CSS from addon scope there is a probably an about:config preference to disable it. Im not sure if there is a preference, so until someone tells you there is, then use the below method.

### Method 2 - Modify the tabs

Use this only if there is no preference to block css. Can copy paste this to scratchpad.

The only parts you need to pay attention to here are the code between `//add your stuff here` and `//end add your stuff here`. So just in `addDiv` and `removeDiv`. I modified your code snippet above a little so the `removeDiv` will restore the css, when you call `windowListener.unregister()`.

You will have to update this code to use once firefox goes multi processes for tabs.

```
var {interfaces: Ci,    utils: Cu} = Components;
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');
var ignoreFrames = false;


function addDiv(theDoc) {
    if (!theDoc) { Cu.reportError('no doc!'); return; } //document not provided, it is undefined likely


    removeDiv(theDoc, true); //remove my div if it was already there, this is just a precaution

    //add your stuff here
    [].slice.call(theDoc.styleSheets).forEach(function(sheet) {
        try {
            [].slice.call(sheet.cssRules).forEach(function(rule) {
                if (rule.media) {
                    rule.media.mediaText = '/*' + escape(rule.media.mediaText) + '*/';
                }
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
    //end add your stuff here
}

function removeDiv(theDoc, skipChecks) {
    if (!skipChecks) {
        if (!theDoc) { Cu.reportError('no doc!'); return; } //document not provided, it is undefined likely
    }

    //add your stuff here
    [].slice.call(theDoc.styleSheets).forEach(function(sheet) {
        try {
            [].slice.call(sheet.cssRules).forEach(function(rule) {
                if (rule.media) {
                    rule.media.mediaText = unescape(rule.media.mediaText.substr(2, rule.media.mediaText.length-2));
                }
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
    //end add your stuff here

}

function listenPageLoad(event) {
    var win = event.originalTarget.defaultView;
    var doc = win.document;
    Cu.reportError('page loaded loc = ' + doc.location);
    if (win.frameElement) {
        //its a frame
        Cu.reportError('its a frame');
        if (ignoreFrames) {
            return;//dont want to watch frames
        }
    }
    addDiv(doc);
}

/*start - windowlistener*/
var windowListener = {
    //DO NOT EDIT HERE
    onOpenWindow: function (aXULWindow) {
        // Wait for the window to finish loading
        let aDOMWindow = aXULWindow.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor).getInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindowInternal || Ci.nsIDOMWindow);
        aDOMWindow.addEventListener("load", function () {
            aDOMWindow.removeEventListener("load", arguments.callee, false);
            windowListener.loadIntoWindow(aDOMWindow, aXULWindow);
        }, false);
    },
    onCloseWindow: function (aXULWindow) {},
    onWindowTitleChange: function (aXULWindow, aNewTitle) {},
    register: function () {
        // Load into any existing windows
        let XULWindows = Services.wm.getXULWindowEnumerator(null);
        while (XULWindows.hasMoreElements()) {
            let aXULWindow = XULWindows.getNext();
            let aDOMWindow = aXULWindow.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor).getInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindowInternal || Ci.nsIDOMWindow);
            windowListener.loadIntoWindow(aDOMWindow, aXULWindow);
        }
        // Listen to new windows
        Services.wm.addListener(windowListener);
    },
    unregister: function () {
        // Unload from any existing windows
        let XULWindows = Services.wm.getXULWindowEnumerator(null);
        while (XULWindows.hasMoreElements()) {
            let aXULWindow = XULWindows.getNext();
            let aDOMWindow = aXULWindow.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor).getInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindowInternal || Ci.nsIDOMWindow);
            windowListener.unloadFromWindow(aDOMWindow, aXULWindow);
        }
        //Stop listening so future added windows dont get this attached
        Services.wm.removeListener(windowListener);
    },
    //END - DO NOT EDIT HERE
    loadIntoWindow: function (aDOMWindow, aXULWindow) {
        if (!aDOMWindow) {
            return;
        }
        if (aDOMWindow.gBrowser) {
            aDOMWindow.gBrowser.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', listenPageLoad, false);
            if (aDOMWindow.gBrowser.tabContainer) {
                //has tabContainer
                //start - go through all tabs in this window we just added to
                var tabs = aDOMWindow.gBrowser.tabContainer.childNodes;
                for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
                    Cu.reportError('DOING tab: ' + i);
                    var tabBrowser = tabs[i].linkedBrowser;
                    var win = tabBrowser.contentWindow;
                    loadIntoContentWindowAndItsFrames(win);
                }
                //end - go through all tabs in this window we just added to
            } else {
                //does not have tabContainer
                var win = aDOMWindow.gBrowser.contentWindow;
                loadIntoContentWindowAndItsFrames(win);
            }
        } else {
            //window does not have gBrowser
        }
    },
    unloadFromWindow: function (aDOMWindow, aXULWindow) {
        if (!aDOMWindow) {
            return;
        }
        if (aDOMWindow.gBrowser) {
            aDOMWindow.gBrowser.removeEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', listenPageLoad, false);
            if (aDOMWindow.gBrowser.tabContainer) {
                //has tabContainer
                //start - go through all tabs in this window we just added to
                var tabs = aDOMWindow.gBrowser.tabContainer.childNodes;
                for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
                    Cu.reportError('DOING tab: ' + i);
                    var tabBrowser = tabs[i].linkedBrowser;
                    var win = tabBrowser.contentWindow;
                    unloadFromContentWindowAndItsFrames(win);
                }
                //end - go through all tabs in this window we just added to
            } else {
                //does not have tabContainer
                var win = aDOMWindow.gBrowser.contentWindow;
                unloadFromContentWindowAndItsFrames(win);
            }
        } else {
            //window does not have gBrowser
        }
    }
};
/*end - windowlistener*/

function loadIntoContentWindowAndItsFrames(theWin) {
    var frames = theWin.frames;
    var winArr = [theWin];
    for (var j = 0; j < frames.length; j++) {
        winArr.push(frames[j].window);
    }
    Cu.reportError('# of frames in tab: ' + frames.length);
    for (var j = 0; j < winArr.length; j++) {
        if (j == 0) {
            Cu.reportError('**checking win: ' + j + ' location = ' + winArr[j].document.location);
        } else {
            Cu.reportError('**checking frame win: ' + j + ' location = ' + winArr[j].document.location);
        }
        var doc = winArr[j].document;
        //START - edit below here
        addDiv(doc);
        if (ignoreFrames) {
            break;
        }
        //END - edit above here
    }
}

function unloadFromContentWindowAndItsFrames(theWin) {
    var frames = theWin.frames;
    var winArr = [theWin];
    for (var j = 0; j < frames.length; j++) {
        winArr.push(frames[j].window);
    }
    Cu.reportError('# of frames in tab: ' + frames.length);
    for (var j = 0; j < winArr.length; j++) {
        if (j == 0) {
            Cu.reportError('**checking win: ' + j + ' location = ' + winArr[j].document.location);
        } else {
            Cu.reportError('**checking frame win: ' + j + ' location = ' + winArr[j].document.location);
        }
        var doc = winArr[j].document;
        //START - edit below here
        removeDiv(doc);
        if (ignoreFrames) {
            break;
        }
        //END - edit above here
    }
}
```

now after copy pasting that. to use it go like this `windowListener.register();` and to remove/restore css call `windowListener.unregister();`

#### builder solution

```
pageMod.PageMod({
     include: "*",
     contentScript: '[].slice.call(document.styleSheets)forEach(function(sheet){try{[].slice.call(sheet.cssRules).forEach(function(rule){if(rule.media){rule.media.mediaText=''}})}catch(err){console.log(err)}});'    
});
```

Comment: Big Big Thanks for that!

Sadly, i still get annoying errors, how should i build up the XPI so that the above code works as expected? Seems like it does not work over mozillas XPI Builder API...

Comment: Copy paste this into scratchpad. It properly runs your code in all tabs. However it deoesnt remove all css. Are you sure about the `media.mediaText` technique? maybe i have a bug and didnt look

Comment: oh yea this definitely wont work for builder, for builder you have to do something else ill edit solution

Comment: So you say i should paste this code into an empty txt file and build the xpi manually?
Yes the media.mediaText technique works really good when run over greasemonkey, but not as xpi...
Oh did not see, thanks for the Builder solution, ill test it now!

Comment: Okay seems like there is a last error, when tested via the builder i get this: console.error: css3blocker: 
  `Message: SyntaxError: missing } after property list
  Stack:
    @resource://jid1-vetssyvh8hl6fq-at-jetpack/css3blocker/lib/main.js:3:undefined`
And i changed you code to this cause two ';' where missing: `'[].slice.call(document.styleSheets)forEach(function(sheet){try{[].slice.call(sheet.cssRules).forEach(function(rule){if(rule.media){rule.media.mediaText='';}});}catch(err){console.log(err)}});'` Im really grateful for your help!

Comment: Again, changed it to `'[].slice.call(document.styleSheets)forEach(function(sheet){try{[].slice.call(sheet.cssRules).forEach(function(rule){if(rule.media){rule.media.mediaText=\'\';}});}catch(err){console.log(err)}});'`, now i get again this: `Message: ReferenceError: pageMod is not defined` Is there nothing that is defined? :/